# UILabel Not Changing Text

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an array in a tableView to record how many cells have checkmarks or not, and tried to have the Label text change based on how many checkmarks there are.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
func setText() {

    if checkmarks == [0: false] {
    self.myLabel.text = "text"
    }
    if checkmarks == [1: false] {
    self.myLabel.text = "text1"
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors, but the text is not changing. Any advice is appreciated.

UPDATE: The array I am trying to take values from is in another class.

Here is that code:

```
var checkmarks = [Int: Bool]()
```

the checkmarks get saved so I thought by writing the above code in a (public class??), my other class files could access it.

Perhaps I need to call checkmarks at the start of the other class file too? Edit: That is an invalid redeclaration my bad.

Thanks for the help

UPDATE 2: The problem was in the interpretation of the array system. I rewrote my code as a loop (which I will add on request) and that fixed it. Thank you all for helping!!

Comment: Is the method getting called? It seems a bit strange that issue would be that the text on the label is not being changed although you do set a new text on it. check if method does get called. Check which of the if statements get called (might be both). Check if you set the text anywhere else. If all of these seem OK then the only thing I can think of is you are not calling it on the main thread. If the method is not getting called or incorrect case is evaluated then you will need to provide more information about your procedure as the issue is most likely not in the code you posted.

Comment: How did you declare `checkmarks`?

Comment: show check mark declaration

Comment: Is this function called on the main thread?

Comment: What is the value of `checkmarks` when this function gets called? You have two if-statements that check if it equals a value, so if `checkmarks` does not equal any of those values, nothing will happen.

Comment: Hi thank you for the replies, I will edit now

Comment: Minding print `checkmarks` before doing your two tests?

Comment: sorry I don't understand :( (I'm a bit of a noob so you're going to have to explain like im 5 im afraid)

Comment: If your `checkmarks` has hundreds of items in the collection, how are you supposed to check for each one of them?

Comment: my checkmarks is unique to one tableview. there are 12 possible. I assumed that as a condition [0: true] that means there are 0 cells with checkmarks. I don't really understand what you are saying, sorry for my poor English :(

Comment: Okay then what about `[5: true]` and `[8: false]`?

Comment: I would assume that means 5 cells with checkmarks or 8 cells without? Do you want me to try those conditions?

Comment: No. Your approach is somewhat misleading. You could just pass an `Integer` from your previous view controller rather than passing a `Dictionary`.

Comment: The view controller that declared checkmarks is forward one from the one Im looking at now. How would I go about doing that, and how does it impact the code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Banterus, why not just have `Int`s instead of a dictionary? Something like `var rowsWithCheckmark: Int` and `var rowsWithoutCheckmark: Int`. Have it declared in the same place as your checkmarks dictionary, except that instead of writing into the dictionary true or false for some number, rather just set the number into the property directly. Then your `setText()` would use the following condition: `if rowsWithoutCheckmark == 0 { self.myLabel.text = "text" }`

Comment: Alternatively, if you insist on a dictionary, it would make more sense to declare it as `[Bool: Int]` rather than `[Int: Bool]`. If you use Ints as keys then you have to check for every possible int to see the associated value. However, there can only be two Bools so you only need to check two keys to know the number of checkmarks. Another upside is that you could easily forget to delete the old value for some int key whereas if you use bools as keys, you are going to overwrite the value (as in, nothing prevents your [Int: Bool] to have content like this: [1: true, 2:true] - clearly wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of my understanding you are trying to show the selected row with tick mark in a tableview, so if it then there is another approach to show it.

consider the following approach.

declare your variables as global to class

```
var selected = [String]()
let colors = ["Apple","Pear", "Banana","Orange",]
```

and your datasource and delegate methods should like similar to this

```
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            if selected.contains(colors[indexPath.row]) {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }else{
                cell.accessoryType = .none
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = colors[indexPath.row]
            return cell;
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return colors.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if selected.contains(colors[indexPath.row]) {
                selected.remove(at: selected.index(of: colors[indexPath.row])!)
            }else{
                selected.append(colors[indexPath.row])
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        } 
}
```

and finally your output will be like this
[image]

Comment: My tableview works fine. My question was asking what is the reason for my declared variable not affecting another class, when I declared it as a global variable? The code I used is similar to yours, but I did not use the extension.

Comment: if it is the case then the reference of the **checkmarks**  object points to something and the static **[0: false]** object which you are comparing is different. So that is the reason why your condition check is not working.

Comment: Hi, I looked into it again and that pretty much fixed it. I rewrote a loop that changed the way the [int: bool] was after printing my checkmarks, I'm gonna accept your answer as best answer as it was the most useful :))